# Div overflowing on another Div having child Divs

Tags: css

I have Div1 with 3 children Divs Div1Child1, Div1Child2, Div1Child3, and then I create one more div Div2. Div2 is overflowing on Div1.
How to prevent this?

My code-

```
<div id="idDivContents">
    <div id="idDivBanner"></div>
    <div id="idDivPoster"></div>
    <div id="idDivProducts"></div>
</div>
    
<div id="idDivFooter"></div>
```

Here idDivFooter is overflowing on idDivContents.
But I need idDivFooter below idDivContents.

Comment: if i take your code run as is it the footer doesn't overflow the main content, so you must have a wrong css we can't see

Comment: Sorry ... but that IS NOT YOUR CODE! That is a html structure ONLY. Such a single structure does not causes overflows on it's own. If you would like to get some help ...  it would be extremly helpful if you would provide your CODE.That means: structure WITH content, CSS and if used with JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue. Since I can't delete this question, I am answering it here-
The problem was with the height of the parent Div. If the height of the parent Div is equal to the sum of the height of the child divs then the Footer div won't overflow.